# reduce function with empty object is not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create object from form elements. For some reason, it is throwing the error.

```
let allInputs = [...formData]; 
allInputs.pop(); //Remove submit button
return allInputs.reduce((userObj, data) => userObj[`${data.name}`] = data.value, {});
```

**Error**

```
userModel.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'last_name' on string ''
```

Comment: Seems like `userObj` is a string?

Comment: `reduce` callbacks need to return the accumulator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return accumulator or in your case `userObj` in each iteration of reduce so your code should look like this.

```
allInputs.reduce((userObj, data) => (userObj[`${data.name}`] = data.value, userObj), {});
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is what you're returning the second time your reducer is called, not what you start with.

You are returning an assignment but should return an object.

```
(userObj, data) => userObj[`${data.name}`] = data.value // <-- this returns the result of the assignment
```

Something like this should work:

```
allInputs.reduce(
  (userObj, data) => Object.assign(userObj, {
    [data.name]: data.value
  }),
  {}
);
```

Note: as mentioned by Vic in the comment, no need for string interpolation, i.e. `${data.name}` -> just `data.name` is enough.

Comment: can this just be: `[data.name]: data.value` instead of `$(...)` ?

Comment: Any reason not to put `userObj` as the first arg to `Object.assign`? This also probably has different behavior from the original for duplicate names.

Comment: @loganfsmyth yeah, it would make more sense to do so. I typed the args in rather mechanically :)